# How to set direction of arrows in shadergraph

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite, shader-graph

I'm pretty new to shader graph and shaders in general. I'm working on a 2D project and I'm trying to make a shader that rotates an arrow to make a flow-like material and use it on a sprite shape.

Basically what I want to do is make a proper version of this:

[image: current arrow]

What I'm currently doing is multiplying the Y position of the position node by an exposed vector 1 and using it in Rotate node (which I know is pretty hacky and won't work if the shape is not an arc.)

[image: shader]

Comment: No all things that can a shader should be a shader tho. Are you those arrows cannot be fixed in just 5 minutes in Blender uv editor?

Comment: I'm doing it on a sprite shape so I was hoping there was a more dynamic way to do it rather than using blender for every shape.

Comment: There is a better way: create one single straight **subdivided** rectangle (sprite or mesh, whatever) with correctly projected texture/arrows, then use shader graph to **bend mesh vertices** (in Object space) and not uv (!). Problem solved

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually looked up bending mesh vertices but all the tutorials I could find for shadergraph were about mesh deformation, is deformation what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aligning UV with arbitrary mesh seems bit hard. Why not bend pre-made mesh instead? Graph below bends vertex positions around axis Z at given point and strength (0 makes mesh invisible tho), but, you can easily replace that `Position` node with `UV` and plug results into `Sample Texture 2D`. I just guess bending a mesh will give you better/easier results.

---

- Create a **subdivided** and **well UV-mapped rectangle plane**
- Bend that plane with a vertex shader (attached graph bends around Z axis)
  [image: bend mesh vertices unity shader graph]

[graph is based on code from Blender source](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/modifiers/intern/MOD_simpledeform.c$150)

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I should go with bending a mesh, seems like the best possible way. Btw is this a picture from HDRP shadergraph?

Comment: It's taken from URP, unity 2020.1, Hybrid renderer v2. But differences are not that great, fundamentals stay the same everywhere